# What date format is required to import entityform submissions via feeds?

Tags: 7, feeds

I am trying to import [entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) submissions. When using [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [feeds entity processor](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_entity_processor) it asks for a default value for the "date submitted". I have tried several date formats and none of them are accepted.

I have tried

m/d/y

mm/dd/yy

mm/dd/yyyy

month dd, year

unix timestamp

What format does this need to be in?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates have to be specified as timestamps. There is a patch for the Feeds entity processor module available to add support for date formats: https://www.drupal.org/node/2708243

With the patch applied, date formats can be the following (among more):

- `yyyy-mm-dd`: 2017-06-30
- `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`: 2017-06-30T08:53:30
- `mm/dd/yyyy`: 06/30/2017
- `mm-dd-yyyy`: 06-30-2017
- `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`: 06/30/2017 08:53:30
- `dd-mm-yyyy`: 30-06-2017
- `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss`: 30-06-2017 08:53:30

The specified user should be an user ID, not an username.

Comment: Wow, thanks MegaChriz. That worked like a charm. You are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Checking the code is seems the validation is done by entity module **entity_property_verify_data_type** which checks for numeric values regarding a date field. So try

```
yyyymmdd
20170627
```

**not working**

[image]

**valid date**

[image]

Comment: unfortunately that didn;t work, I get the following error: EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 736 of /sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

Comment: I just tested this with the __Node entity processor - EXPERIMENTAL__ version and it works as expected. So the must be some other problem on your system. I used the latest entity and feeds* modules.

Comment: Do you get a real exception? On what entity? I guess to have to be more specific with your question then.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I didn't specify the entity. Sometimes when you write out questions you don't realize how much pertinent info you miss as you know all about your own problem. I am trying to import entityform submissions. I have updated my question with this huge gap in my question.

Comment: I realized that I did specify the entity I was using in the actual title of the post when I first asked this question, just not in the body (was also specified in the screenshot). Still I was not as clear as I could have been but at least I wasn't as absent-minded as I thought.

Comment: I only have less than a day left on the bounty. I would love to assign it to you. DO you have some time to figure this out for entityform?

Comment: Hi Nigel, I've created a patch to add better date support for Feeds entity processor. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2708243. See also https://www.drupal.org/node/2868044 for my answer on what to type in the "User" field for an entityform submission.

Comment: The patch of MegaChriz would solve the user input which is great but will not solve the exception. I've retested using (DEV 2017-May-26) of  FeedsEntityProcessorEntityform and still cannot reproduce. @NigelWaters I hope the patch works for you :).

Could it be your modules are not all up to date?

Comment: I just tested and I do still get the error as well.

Comment: Very weird. Thanks for the bounty though :)